# JPQL Insert by selecting query not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have two below **entity**. One is **MatchTable** another is **MatchLog**.

```
@Entity
public class MatchTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Integer primaryID;

    @ManyToOne
    private Integer suspectedID;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer status;

    //getter and setter

}



@Entity
public class MatchLog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private MatchTable referenceID;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long primaryID;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long suspectedID;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer status;

    //getter and setter
}
```

If **status** of **MatchTable** change,these row will be inserted into **MatchLog**. I have tried with the below **JPQL** query.

```
@Query("INSERT INTO MatchLog (referenceID.id,primaryID,suspectedID,status) SELECT id,primaryID,suspectedID,status from MatchTable where (primaryID = :ID or suspectedID = :ID)")
int updateMatchLogTable(@Param("ID") long ID);
```

But this **JPQL** query is not working. Please suggest me what will be the JPQL query to **insert** change rows from **MatchTable** to **MatchLog**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, JPA does not support "insert into select". You can change as native query.